# How to sort the documents based on date strings in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to sort my collection based on the date values using mongoose. When I use the sort function it does not work as intended.

Following is the query I use.

```
const filters = {};
filters.spacecategory = { $in: spaceId };
const sortingQuery = { publishedDate: -1 };
const filteredFeeds = await Feed.find(filters).sort(sortingQuery);
```

publishedDate has the following format
The date format in the MongoDB is "Fri Mar 29, 2019 21:21:25 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"

Help is very much appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For this, you need to use the aggregation pipeline. Before sorting use [$dateFromString] in the project [1](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/) for converting string to date.

Like:

```
db.collectionname.aggregate([
    {
       $project: {
          date: {
             $dateFromString: {
                dateString: '$date',
                timezone: 'America/New_York'
             }
          }
       }
    },
    {
        $sort : {"date" : 1}
    }

    ])
```

Comment: I tried out this option. But I got stuck with an error.
Following is my code.

const filteredFeeds = await Feed.aggregate([
      { $match: filters },
      {
        $project: {
          publishedDate: {
            $dateFromString: {
              dateString: '$publishedDate',
              // timezone: 'America/New_York',
            },
          },
        },
      },
      {
        $sort: { publishedDate: 1 },
      },
    ]);

Comment: Unhandled Rejection at: Promise Promise {
  <rejected> RangeError: Invalid status code: undefined

I get this error. publishedDate is what I have in my model

Comment: You are missing date format. Please check documentation for $datefromstring function

Comment: Can I convert this format: Fri Mar 29, 2019 21:21:25 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)? because this is what am trying to convert and sort

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196876/discussion-between-omnathpp-and-rajat-goel).